# Stylesheet not being applied on page load

Tags: javascript, html, sass

Can someone offer me some directions for debugging this problem I'm having with a project I'm working on. Hit this [url](http://itsafieldday.com) and you'll see the naked HTML doc for roughly 1-3 seconds before the stylesheet kicks in?

Comment: Do you order them in correct manner? they should be loaded at the top of the page. seems your page is behaving like this because you have some references at the bottom of page.

Comment: All of your styles are being loaded in a no script block.  Is that on purpose?  Seems wrong

Comment: Try moving the group of `<link>` tags inside the `<noscript>` tag above the `<link>` to google api. It's probably the network request that is causing the lag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest way I think is to move:

```
    <script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

to the top of the page. You have some css in "js" files and thats why unless js is loaded - you see this pure HTML code.

Edit: of course make sure jquery.js is before that ;).

Comment: Moving the scripts to the top of the page worked like a charm. The theme (not my choice) came with those <noscript> tags. When moving up the js I tried also deleted them and then the stylesheets got f-ed up.  Thanks.